# Android CheckBox with right-aligned checking button/box

Tags: android, android-widget

I am fairly new to Android (find it most fun, btw) and I was wondering...

How can I create an Android CheckBox with the label to the left and the checking button/box aligned to the right (pretty much a switch of the way this widget is drawn by default)? Like the way a checkbox preference normally looks like...

I am looking for the most elegant/short-coded version possible, if there is one. I mean other than creating your own View/ViewGroup with layouts, empty-labeled CheckBoxes and TextViews, etc...

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `CheckedTextView`, which is the widget used by multiple-choice `ListView` widgets.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer. I've seen that widget in the API, but apparently I dodn't give it enough attention. I'll take a better look...

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

CommonsWare's answer is absolutely right but there is one more option which you can use and it's quite easier than CheckedTextView. You can use ***simple_item_list_multiple_choice***. it will create list with chekcbox and labels on left and as on the name of extra work you just have to define one ListView in your main.xml nothing else.

I hope it will help.